# how to read csv file row by row in django?

Tags: python, django, csv

I would like to make the first row in csv file as the field name in Django.
Is it possible?
I would like to read the csv file row by row.

It's my code.

```
if request.FILES:
    form = SalaryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        # request.session['salary'] = request.POST["salary"]
        # salary = Salary.object.get(id=request.session['salary'])
        print(request.FILES['fileUpload'].name)
        csvfile = request.FILES['fileUpload'].read()
        encoding = chardet.detect(csvfile)['encoding']
        print (encoding)
        if encoding is None:
            encoding = 'CP932'
        if encoding !='utf-8':
            csvfile = csvfile.decode(encoding, 'replace').encode('utf-8')
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

but now I the reader can only store Alphabet cannot store words.
my CSV file is like this:

'registration_number', 'name', 'kana', 'month', 'day', 'client_code', 'row', 'business_days', 'working_days', 'count', 'early_late_time', 'normal_time', 'over_time', 'holiday_time', 'night_time', 'working_time', 'basic_salary', 'regular_attendance', 'reqular_attendace_allowance', 'over_time_ratio', 'holiday_time_ratio', 'night_time_ratio', 'fare_day', 'fare', 'employment_insurance', 'personally', 'spouse', 'dependent', 'special_allowance', 'adjustment', 'income_tax', 'advanced_payment', 'suspense_payment', 'health_insurance', 'employment_pension', 'employment_insurance_amount', 'no_payment'
"223","山野 薫","ﾔﾏﾉ ｶｵﾘ",1,10,"1101",1,17,16,,＼1,,,,,＼8,800,350,0,＼1,＼1,＼0,,8300,1,0,9,0,9200,,2260,,,9557,15928,818,0
"018","波多野 未樹","ﾊﾀﾉ ﾐｷ",1,15,"2301",1,21,20,,,,,,,＼8,800,200,0,＼1,＼1,＼0,300,6000,0,,,,,,3360,,,,,,0

I would like to use the first row as my field name, since every time the uploaded files got different format.

thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead of `csv.reader`. With the `fieldnames` parameter omitted, the first row of the file will be used to determine field names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to store the field names separately, coz every time the field name will change, so I need to store it so that I can retrieve the data later.

Comment: From the documentation, adding `reader.fieldnames` to your code should give you the field names once the DictReader object has been initialised with your data. :)